# Search for a txt file,if it exists append a new line to it.If it doesn't,then create the file

Tags: bash, shell

I tried it using the normal commands

```
echo "${OPTARG}">>~/movie_history.txt
```

but >> works only if the file exists.
Is there any way I can make this work through shell scripting?

Comment: [`>>` will create the file if it does not exist](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Appending-Redirected-Output). Do you have any evidence to back up your claim?

Comment: I told it doesn't create the file

Comment: Well, you got bad advice. Read the documentation and try it for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just space out `>>`, some bash shells are sensitive to this.

Comment: /bin/scraper: 128: /bin/scraper: cannot create !~/movie_history.txt: Directory nonexistent
This is the error I get when I try the code you said

Comment: Try putting spaces between '>>!' and everything else.

Comment: bin/scraper: 129: /bin/scraper: cannot create !: Permission denied
This is the error it is displaying after adding the spaces.Also,optarg is not empty.

Comment: Use just >> but with spaces. If this doesn't work, can you say what's the output of echo $SHELL?

Comment: Which version, exactly, of `bash` supports `>>!` as a distinct operator?

Comment: Thanks a lot.I should have just added >> with spaces.Silly of me.Thank you! :)

Comment: @chepner I stand corrected, I confused tcsh and bash shells (I have both running on a machine). Thanks - edited.